# Create and register TinyMCE plugin with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Using the jQuery TinyMCE, I'm trying to register a custom "plugin" (it's really just a menu within the toolbar)

I'm trying to get this registered, but the code I found on http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/menu_button.php doesn't seem to work with the jquery version of TinyMCE.  Ideally, I'd like to have my custom plugin code in a separate js file also.

TinyMce init script

```
// Start TinyMce Editor
    $('#Template_Html').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',

        // General options
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "marcusinserts,autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "fullscreen,preview,code,|,cleanup,removeformat,|,undo,redo,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,bullist,numlist,|,sub,sup,|,template,viewhtmlversion,taginserts",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,formatselect,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,tablecontrols,|,charmap,iespell,advhr",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        //theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,advhr",
        //theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: false,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        //content_css:'/Portal/Content/admin.css',

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

        // Preview options
        plugin_preview_width: "725",
        plugin_preview_height: "600",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values: {
            username: "Some User",
            staffid: "991234"
        },

        // View HTML Version insert button
        setup: function (ed) {
            ed.addButton('viewhtmlversion', {
                title: 'Insert View HTML version link',
                image: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/themes/advanced/img/custom-icon-view-html.gif")',
                onclick: function() {
                    ed.focus();
                    ed.selection.setContent('<a href="{VR_HOSTED_LINK}">Click to view this email in a browser</a>');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // End TinyMce Editor
```

The plugin I'm trying to create and setup:

```
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.MarcusInserts', {
createControl: function (n, cm) {
    switch (n) {
        case 'taginserts':
            var c = cm.createMenuButton('taginserts', {
                title: 'Tag Inserts',
                image: '/Scripts/tinymce/themes/advanced/img/custom-icon-view-html.gif',
                icons: false
            });

            c.onRenderMenu.add(function (c, m) {
                m.add({ title: 'View in Browser', onclick: function () {
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'Some item 1');
                } 
                });

                m.add({ title: 'Forward Link', onclick: function () {
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'Some item 2');
                } 
                });

                m.add({ title: 'Social Media', onclick: function () {
                    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'Some item 2');
                }
                });
            });

            // Return the new menu button instance
            return c;
    }

    return null;
}
});

// Register plugin with a short name
tinymce.PluginManager.add('marcus-inserts', tinymce.plugins.MarcusInserts);
```

Comment: please post your full tinymce config/init

Comment: great... exact the querstion I need

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't state whether or not you're actually trying to load this plugin from the plugin folder - so this statement might not actually apply to your problem but I'll add for completeness:

*Because the Jquery version of TinyMCE changes the order in which things are initiated (eg: you can't reference the tinymce object before you've called `$('textarea').tinymce(...)`, you can't add the plugin in the same way as the simple plugin example on their site. You have to create a standalone plugin.*

**I'm going to presume that you've followed the instructions on [How to create an TinyMCE plugin here.](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin)**

The issue you've got is that you're loading the plugin: `plugins: "marcusinserts,...` but at the bottom of your plugin you're registering the plugin with the reference

`tinymce.PluginManager.add('marcus-inserts', tinymce.plugins.MarcusInserts);`

try changing that to:

`tinymce.PluginManager.add('marcusinserts', tinymce.plugins.MarcusInserts);` (note the removal of the - between the words marcus and inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I haven't looked at this for a while, but I will try it shortly and let you know how it works!  And yes, I was following the doc you referenced above, just couldn't get it to work with the jquery version.  Hopefully this will help though! - Matt

Comment: Hi @mmillican, how'd it go? Were you able to add the plugin successfully?